# Styling the asp.net charting controls

Tags: asp.net, charts, dundas, asp.net-charts

Using the [ASP.Net Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en), which [are a subset](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexgor/archive/2008/11/07/microsoft-chart-control-vs-dundas-chart-control.aspx) of the [Dundas Chart Controls](http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/NET/index.aspx),

How can I make charts that look like this:

[image]

Instead of this:

[image: MS Chart Example]

EDIT: I've made [some progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137157/force-a-gap-between-points-on-the-x-axis-ms-net-chart-controls-column-chart), since asking this question. The styling elements that improve the default graph in both Dundas and MSChart are:

- Round Corners on the chart container
- Background colours and gradients on chart container
- Transparency on column colours
- Alignment of columns in the x axis (bizarely, MSChart defaults to z axis alignment)
- Area 3D wall width

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a bit late, but I was playing with the chart for a project I'm working on.

```
Color="#960080ff"
```

The first set of two digits in the color are for the alpha channel. I've got it set for 96 which is semi transparent.

enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Area3DStyle.Enable3D property to true.

More info about the 3D style can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489232%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: That's true, but sadly, the default 3d styles are even uglier than the default 2d styles. I'm looking for a way to add transparencies and gradients (as well as 3d). Thanks for that link though. It look's like there's a bit more documentation there.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't understand how to make 3d chart series transparent. Only way to do that I've found is to use SemiTransparent pallete. But that destroys my selected BrightPastel pallete whit I want use. 

In the examples are 3d charts, which are using BrightPastel too but are also transparent. I haven't discovered way they are doing it.